Linearity of mass-spring-damper displacment and maximum displacment
Is a mass-spring-damper considered system a linear system, when looking at the mass displacement?
If so, what does being a linear system actually mean? I have read the detention of linearity (Additivity and Homogeneity), but since the governing equations are differential, how do I see the linearity?
And what if I look at something like the maximum displacement? Even if the function of displacement is linear, a function of the maximum displacement seems non-linear to me. Can that be showed?

Yes, the damped mass spring system is a linear system. It is a case of damped harmonic motion. When we say the system is linear, it means that we can write the equation of motion
$$\mathrm{d}_t^2x(t)+2\gamma\mathrm{d}_tx(t)+\omega_0^2x(t)=0$$
in the form $$\mathscr{L}[x(t)]=0$$
where $\mathscr{L}$ is a linear operator, with the properties
$$\begin{align*}\mathscr{L}[f+g]&=\mathscr{L}[f]+\mathscr{L}[g]\\
\mathscr{L}[cf]&=c\mathscr{L}[f]\end{align*}$$
Here is your EOM written explicitly in that form:
$$\begin{align}
\left[\mathrm{d}_t^2+2\gamma\mathrm{d}_t+\omega_0^2\right]x(t)=0
\end{align}$$
I will leave it as an exercise to show that $\mathscr{L}=\mathrm{d}_t^2+2\gamma\mathrm{d}_t+\omega_0^2$ is a linear operator.

Thank you for this answer.
So i understand the mathamatical definition you gave. But what does being a linear system actually mean? When i imagine 'linearity' of x(t), i imagine a function of form x(t) = a*x+b. How does this connect to the mathamatical definition you gave?

It means that the solutions to the homogeneous equation form a vector space. Sums of solutions are also solutions. The connection is that all terms are linear in $x$ and its derivatives. So, there are no terms like $x(t)^2$, and there is no mixing of derivatives into terms like $x(t)\dot{x}(t)$.
